# Dockerfile: COPY a file relative to local home

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In a Dockerfile I want to copy a file relative to my local home inside the images's home.

So I have tried many variations of:

```
COPY "~/.m2/settings.xml" "$HOME/.m2/settings2.xml"
```

But I get errors like

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder635958043/~/.m2/settings.xml: no such file or directory
```

How can I copy a file relative to my local home inside the image?

Comment: You can't.  You can only copy files from the directory tree you name in the `docker build` command (usually, the directory containing the `Dockerfile`).

Comment: The COPY is relative to the build context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source for the COPY command is the build context. The build context is included in the last argument to the `docker build` command, often a `.` which means the current directory. This location is sent to the docker engine before running any steps of the Dockerfile, using a tar file, in the default/classic builder. Therefore, to keep builds running fast, you want to keep this directory small by not sending over the entire hard drive contents. This is even more important when building locally since you could potentially start sending files recursively if you were to include docker's temporary directory in the folders being sent.

All this means you should move any files you want to include in the COPY source parameter to be inside the build context, typically the same location as your Dockerfile.